# Obj C - Word Line Truncation

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want to show my long text in a UILabel. But, My design having small size of frame for that UILabel. So, i want to truncate my long text like this[see below]:

Ex:

UILabel Text: "I want to show my long text in a UILabel"

Recent Result: [Using lineBreakMode:]

1. I want to s........a UILabel
2. I want to s.....
3. I want to s

Expected Result: "I want to...."

[Note:  I want truncation after the word which can fit within their label frame.]

I hope that you can sense about my expected result. Sorry for my English!.

Comment: If you're meaning you want to only add ellipses after a full word, and not in the middle of a word, you should make that clearer.

Comment: I'm new for Obj C.How to add ellipses.

Comment: Yes.After the full word.

Comment: @jprofitt I think OP wants to avoid truncate in middle of the word. Already, the OP given short note in their question. Am also wants solution for this question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OP excepted result and the @Naveen logic, I develop the code which works but with some restriction.

Restriction:

1. Sometimes, extending that label width by adding 10.0 value.
2. don't give any spaces at begin and end of label text.

Design:

Controls: A UIButton, UITextField, UILabel

1. Type your text in the UITextField.
2. Do Action to display your excepted result in the UILabel.

Code:

```
-(IBAction)actionDisplayTextWithTruncate:(id)sender{

lblFinalResult.frame=CGRectMake(60, 345, 55, 21);

NSString *strGivenText, *strFuncResult, *stringThatFits;
int spaceCount;

//Custom Truncate Function
strGivenText=txtFldGivenText.text;
arrForGivenText_Words = [strGivenText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

stringThatFits=@"";
strFuncResult=@"";

for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrForGivenText_Words count]; i++)
{
    /* must follow @" %@" - a space before %@ */
    NSString *tempString = [stringThatFits stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",    arrForGivenText_Words[i]];
    CGRect boundingRect = [tempString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(999, 999)                                                        options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:lblFinalResult.font} context:nil];

    if (boundingRect.size.width > lblFinalResult.frame.size.width) //Breakpoint1 
    {
        if(i==0){
           [lblFinalResult setText:@"..."];
           return;
        }
        else{
            for (int j = 0 ; j < i; j++)
            {
                 strFuncResult = [strFuncResult stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ",arrForGivenText_Words[j]];
                 NSLog(@"Present_a1: %@", strFuncResult);
            }
            strFuncResult = [strFuncResult substringToIndex:strFuncResult.length-(strFuncResult.length>0)];
            lblFinalResult.frame= CGRectMake(lblFinalResult.frame.origin.x,   lblFinalResult.frame.origin.y, lblFinalResult.frame.size.width+10, lblFinalResult.frame.size.height);
            strFuncResult=[strFuncResult stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
            [lblFinalResult setText:strFuncResult];
            return;
        }
    }
    else{
        stringThatFits = tempString;
        NSLog(@"Present_a2: %@", stringThatFits);
    }
}
[lblFinalResult setText:stringThatFits];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is API for this. If you are not getting answers. You can use the below logic to achieve This is not optimum logic.

```
    -(NSString *) textThatFits:(NSString *) originalText font:(UIFont *) font
    {
        NSArray *array = [originalText componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *stringThatFits;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < [array count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *tempString = [stringThatFits stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", array[i]];
            CGRect boundingRect = [tempString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(999, 999)
                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                                    context:nil];
            if (boundingRect.size.width < self.yourLabel.width) {
                return stringThatFits;
            }
            else
            {
                stringThatFits = tempString;
            }
        }
          return stringThatFits;
    }
```

Comment: Am also searching for any pre-defined property for this type of truncation. But, nothing i got. And using your logic, i post one solution for OP excepting result.

Comment: Is **boundingRectWithSize** works only for one line of text even i put numberOfLines for my UILabel is 3. And also set appropriate height for 3 lines of text.

Comment: if you want to have multiple lines just specify numberOfLines as '0'. On boundingRectWithSize, can you describe more with some code?

Comment: In my Answer, i put comment a line as **Breakpoint1**. This line check  only width for truncation. But, i also want to check height because of  my UILabel has multiple line of text. How can i code for this?.